# How to return a single integer from this WMIObject in PowerShell (Temperature)

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

```
    $temps = Get-CIMInstance MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -Namespace "root/wmi"
    $temps | Select-Object -Property InstanceName,@{n="TempF";e={(($_.currenttemperature /10 -273.15) *1.8 +32)}}
```

I cannot seem to select-object -ExpandProperty like usual to get just the TempF result:

```
    InstanceName            TempF
    ------------            -----
    ACPI\ThermalZone\THM__0 77.09
```

Just want the 77.09

Bonus points if can display in Celsius :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using powershell 3 or above you can call the property by using the member name of the object.

Example:

`$temps.TempF` Would return your result of `77.09`

```
$tempt = Get-CimInstance MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -Namespace "root/wmi"
$temps = ($tempt | Select-Object -Property InstanceName,@{n="TempF";e={(($_.currenttemperature /10 -273.15) *1.8 +32)}},@{n="TempC";e={($_.currenttemperature /10 -273.15)}})
```

I have also added Celcius to the object/variable `$temps`.

You can get either Fahrenheit `$temps.tempF` or Celsius `$temps.tempC`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $tempt = Get-CimInstance MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -Namespace "root/wmi"
    $tempF = ($tempt | Select-Object -Property InstanceName,@{n="TempF";e={(($_.currenttemperature /10 -273.15) *1.8 +32)}})|Select-Object -ExpandProperty TempF
```

Had an epiphany and figured it out.